# Unexplained Error in Visual studio c++ compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc

Hi I am encountering issue with the following codes;
at this line

```
constexpr static Test<T> Reset = Test<T>();
```

> error C2027: use of undefined type NS::Test

But I have no issue compiling this codes in Linux gcc. How can i build this codes in Windows VS C++?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>

namespace NS
{
    template <class T>
    class Test
    {
    public:
        constexpr static Test<T> Reset = Test<T>();

    private: 
    };

    template <class T>
    constexpr Test<T> Test<T>::Reset;
} 

struct Def
{
    static constexpr uint16_t Init = 0xffff;
    
};

using  MY = NS::Test<Def>;

struct TransactionInfo
{
    MY          my;
};
```

Comment: I reproduced the error: [https://godbolt.org/z/n81bhncEr](https://godbolt.org/z/n81bhncEr)

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix is to make `Reset` a function instead of a value.

Member functions of templated types are defined "on-demand", which kicks the can down the road to the callsite, where we know `Test<T>` will be complete.

```
namespace NS
{
    template <class T>
    class Test
    {
    public:
        constexpr static Test<T> Reset() {
          return {};
        }

    private: 
    };

}
```

Comment: Honestly, I'm surprised G++ is letting that fly in the first place. `Test<T>` is clearly an incomplete type at the point of definition. [From the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#static.data-4): "The declaration of an inline static data member (which is a definition)..."